# How to use navigation using functional component - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

How can I use navigation  using class component, the screens that I currently have on my app are functional components, and this is how I'm able to navigate from one page to another, but If try to implement this using functional comopenent it doesn't work.

```
export default function Activity({navigation}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}> 
     
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

How Can I implemented in here :/
I tried

> this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')

and I got the following error/warning

> cannot update a component while rendering a different component

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
     render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}> 
     
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: if the component in which you are trying to use navigation is a child component, you have to pass navigation as props from the parent component

Comment: @nazmul how can pass props.

Comment: if the parent is functional component , <Child navigation={navigation}/> ,
and in case of class component, <Child navigation={this.props.navigation}/> and you can accept it in the child component as any other props.

Answer (score 0):

For my navigation, I had to add at the beginning of the file this importation

import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

And in my functional component

const navigation = useNavigation()

Like this :
[image]